# regular expressions: find every word that appears exactly one time in my document

Tags: regex

Trying to learn regular expressions. As a practice, I'm trying to find every word that appears exactly one time in my document -- in linguistics this is a hapax legemenon (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax_legomenon)

So I thought the following expression give me the desired result:

`\w{1}`

But this doesn't work. The `\w` returns a character not a whole word. Also it does not appear to be giving me characters that appear only once (it actually returns 25873 matches -- which I assume are all alphanumeric characters). Can someone give me an example of how to find "hapax legemenon" with a regular expression?

Comment: What flavour of Regular expressions are you using (ie what language are you programming in?)

Comment: umm, right now I'm using a XML editor that recognizes regular expressions in its "Find and Replace" feature (I think it said something about Pearl though) Normally, I use PHP when programming. Can you show me how it would look in both languages?

Comment: +1 for the interesting link to hapax legomenon

Comment: From your current understanding of regular expressions as evidenced by your question (no offense meant), I think it's a good idea if you first [read a basic regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info) before embarking on a hard question such as this one. BTW, it's Perl, not Pearl.

Comment: @tim - none taken - i definitely in my infancy. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're trying to do this as a learning exercise, you picked a very hard problem :)

First of all, here is the solution:

```
\b(\w+)\b(?<!\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)(?!.*\b\1\b)
```

Now, here is the explanation:

- We want to match a word. This is `\b\w+\b` - a run of one or more (`+`) word characters (`\w`), with a 'word break' (`\b`) on either side. A word break happens between a word character and a non-word character, so this will match between (e.g.) a word character and a space, or at the beginning and the end of the string. We also capture the word into a backreference by using parentheses (`(...)`). This means we can refer to the match itself later on.
- Next, we want to exclude the possibility that this word has already appeared in the string. This is done by using a **negative lookbehind** - `(?<! ... )`. A negative lookbehind *doesn't* match if its contents match the string up to this point. So we want to *not* match if the word we have matched has already appeared. We do this by using a backreference (`\1`) to the already captured word. The final match here is `\b\1\b.*\b\1\b` - two copies of the current match, separated by any amount of string (`.*`).
- Finally, we don't want to match if there is another copy of this word anywhere in the rest of the string. We do this by using **negative lookahead** - `(?! ... )`. Negative lookaheads don't match if their contents match at this point in the string. We want to match the current word after any amount of string, so we use (`.*\b\1\b`).

Here is an example (using C#):

```
var s = "goat goat leopard bird leopard horse";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, @"\b(\w+)\b(?<!\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)(?!.*\b\1\b)"))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

Output:

```
bird
horse
```

Comment: Good explanation and introduction of advanced topics. +1

Comment: Wow, that's almost majestic in it's beauty.  I take back my previous comment about it being an ugly regex. +1  (I wonder how fast this is?)

Comment: wow - a hard problem indeed. Should I make this the official answer? Seems like people like this one.

Comment: @OverZealous: I wouldn't expect it to be very fast, but it's not horrifically slow. On my laptop (running in Linqpad) it takes about 15 seconds for 10,000 words (of *Lorem Ipsum*).

Answer (score 4):

It can be done in a single regex if your regex engine supports infinite repetition inside lookbehind assertions (e. g. .NET):

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @"(       # Match and capture into backreference no. 1:
     \b       # (from the start of the word)
     \p{L}+   # a succession of letters
     \b       # (to the end of a word).
    )         # End of capturing group.
    (?<=      # Now assert that the preceding text contains:
     ^        # (from the start of the string)
     (?:      # (Start of non-capturing group)
      (?!     #  Assert that we can't match...
       \b\1\b #  the word we've just matched.
      )       #  (End of lookahead assertion)
      .       #  Then match any character.
     )*       # Repeat until...
     \1       # we reach the word we've just matched.
    )         # End of lookbehind assertion.
    # We now know that we have just matched the first instance of that word.
    (?=       # Now look ahead to assert that we can match the following:
     (?:      # (Start of non-capturing group)
      (?!     #  Assert that we can't match again...
       \b\1\b #  the word we've just matched.
      )       #  (End of lookahead assertion)
      .       #  Then match any character.
     )*       # Repeat until...
     $        # the end of the string.
    )         # End of lookahead assertion.", 
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResults.Success) {
    // matched text: matchResults.Value
    // match start: matchResults.Index
    // match length: matchResults.Length
    matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: Well, in any case I would go for a more readable solution, even this results in a line more code or a loop. If performance is an argument: upgrade the machine running that code ;-)

Comment: Almost, but not quite. `"goat goat goa leopard bird leopard horse goat"` - "goa" is valid but not captured.

Comment: @Porges: Right. I added the word boundaries around the backreferences.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to match an English word, the *best* form is:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

The problem with `\w` is that it also includes `_` and numeric digits `0-9`.

If you need to include other characters, you can append them after the `Z` but before the `]`.  Or, you might need to normalize the input text first.

Now, if you want a count of all words, or just to see words that don't appear more than once, you can't do that with a single regex.  You'll need to invest some time in programming more complex logic.  It may very well need to be backed by a database or some sort of memory structure to keep track of the count.  After you parse and count the whole text, you can search for words that have a count of `1`.

Comment: Of course it can be done in a single regex. Not that that's the solution of choice, though :)

Comment: I dunno, regular expressions aren't [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness#Non-Turing-complete_languages) - that would be one nasty regex!! X-D

Answer (score 1):

`(\w+){1}` will match each word.
After that you could always perfrom the count on the matches....

Answer (score 1):

Higher level solution:

Create an array of your matches:

```
preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z]+)/", $text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Let PHP count your array elements:

```
$tmp_array = array_count_values($matches[1]);
```

Iterate over the tmp array and check the word count:

```
foreach ($tmp_array as $word => $count) {
    echo $word . '  ' . $count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Low level but does what you want:

Pass your text in an array using split:

```
$array = split('\s+', $text);
```

Iterate over that array:

```
foreach ($array as $word) { ... }
```

Check each word if it is a word:

```
if (!preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]/', $word) continue;
```

Add the word to a temporary array as key:

```
if (!$tmp_array[$word]) $tmp_array[$word] = 0;
$tmp_array[$word]++;
```

After the loop. Iterate over the tmp array and check the word count:

```
foreach ($tmp_array as $word => $count) {
    echo $word . '  ' . $count;
}
```